# AWS EKS - Terraform does not create load balancer after applying LoadBalancer service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I have 1 deployment and 1 service configurations:

**Deployment**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: dashboard-backend-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 2
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: dashboard-backend
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: dashboard-backend
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: dashboard-backend
                  image: $BACKEND_IMAGE
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  env:
                      - name: NODE_ENV
                        value: $NODE_ENV
                      - name: PORT
                        value: '3000'
                      - name: ACCESS_TOKEN_JWT_KEY
                        value: $ACCESS_TOKEN_JWT_KEY
                      - name: REFRESH_TOKEN_JWT_KEY
                        value: $REFRESH_TOKEN_JWT_KEY
                      - name: GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID
                        value: $GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID
                      - name: GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
                        value: $GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
                      - name: GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI
                        value: $GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI
                      - name: GH_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID
                        value: $GH_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID
                      - name: GH_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
                        value: $GH_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
                      - name: GITHUB_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI
                        value: $GITHUB_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI
                      - name: MIXPANEL_TOKEN
                        value: $MIXPANEL_TOKEN
                      - name: FRONTEND_URL
                        value: $FRONTEND_URL
                      - name: CLI_TOKEN_JWT_KEY
                        value: $CLI_TOKEN_JWT_KEY
                      - name: DATABASE_URL
                        value: $DATABASE_URL
```

**Service**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: backend-service
    annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: $SSL_CERTIFICATE_ARN
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
spec:
    selector:
        app: dashboard-backend
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
        - name: https
          protocol: TCP
          port: 3000
          targetPort: 3000
```

I have a cluster, AWS EKS, configured. I run this command:
`kubectl apply -f=./k8s/backend-deployment.yaml -f=./k8s/backend-service.yaml`, of course, when `kubectl` is "connected" to my AWS EKS cluster.

Output of command:

```
Using kubectl version: Client Version: v1.26.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Using aws-iam-authenticator version: {"Version":"0.6.2","Commit":"..."}
deployment.apps/dashboard-backend-deployment unchanged
service/backend-service unchanged
```

When I enter the load balancers section in `EC2` service in AWS, there are no load balancers at all. Why?

These are the Terraform files, I used to deploy my cluster:

**eks-cluster**:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eks_cluster_policy" {
  version = "2012-10-17"

  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["eks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cluster" {
  name               = "${var.project}-Cluster-Role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.eks_cluster_policy.json

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Stack = "backend"
      Name  = "${var.project}-eks-cluster-iam-role",
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cluster_AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.cluster.name
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "main" {
  name     = "${var.project}-cluster"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn
  version  = "1.24"

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = flatten([aws_subnet.public[*].id, aws_subnet.private[*].id])
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = true
    public_access_cidrs     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Stack = "backend"
      Name  = "${var.project}-eks-cluster",
    }
  )

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.cluster_AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
  ]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "eks_cluster" {
  name        = "${var.project}-cluster-sg"
  description = "Cluster communication with worker nodes"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Stack = "backend"
      Name  = "${var.project}-cluster-sg"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "cluster_inbound" {
  description              = "Allow worker nodes to communicate with the cluster API Server"
  from_port                = 443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.eks_cluster.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.eks_nodes.id
  to_port                  = 443
  type                     = "ingress"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "cluster_outbound" {
  description              = "Allow cluster API Server to communicate with the worker nodes"
  from_port                = 1024
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.eks_cluster.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.eks_nodes.id
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "egress"
}
```

**EKS WORKER NODES**

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eks_node_policy" {
  version = "2012-10-17"

  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "node" {
  name               = "${var.project}-Worker-Role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.eks_node_policy.json

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Stack = "backend"
      Name  = "${var.project}-eks-node-iam-role",
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "node_AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.node.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "node_AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.node.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "node_AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.node.name
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "main" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.main.name
  node_group_name = var.project
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.node.arn
  subnet_ids      = aws_subnet.private[*].id

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 2
    min_size     = 1
  }

  ami_type       = "AL2_x86_64"
  capacity_type  = "ON_DEMAND"
  disk_size      = 20
  instance_types = ["t3.small"]

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Stack = "backend"
      Name  = "${var.project}-eks-node-group",
    }
  )

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.node_AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.node_AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.node_AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
  ]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "eks_nodes" {
  name        = "${var.project}-node-sg"
  description = "Security group for all nodes in the cluster"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }


  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Stack                                          = "backend"
      Name                                           = "${var.project}-node-sg"
      "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-cluster" = "owned"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "nodes_internal" {
  description              = "Allow nodes to communicate with each other"
  from_port                = 0
  protocol                 = "-1"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.eks_nodes.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.eks_nodes.id
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "ingress"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "nodes_cluster_inbound" {
  description              = "Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane"
  from_port                = 1025
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.eks_nodes.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.eks_cluster.id
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "ingress"
}
```

**VPC**

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name                                           = "${var.project}-vpc",
      "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-cluster" = "shared"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count             = var.availability_zones_count
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, count.index)
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name                                           = "${var.project}-public-subnet",
      "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-cluster" = "shared"
      "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                       = 1
    }
  )

  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count             = var.availability_zones_count
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, count.index + var.availability_zones_count)
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name                                           = "${var.project}-private-sg"
      "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-cluster" = "shared"
      "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"              = 1
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-igw",
    }
  )

  depends_on = [aws_vpc.main]
}

resource "aws_route_table" "primary" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-primary-route-table",
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "internet_access" {
  count          = var.availability_zones_count
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public[count.index].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.primary.id
}

resource "aws_eip" "main" {
  vpc = true

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-ngw-ip"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "main" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.main.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public[0].id


  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-ngw"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_route" "main" {
  route_table_id         = aws_vpc.main.default_route_table_id
  nat_gateway_id         = aws_nat_gateway.main.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "public_sg" {
  name   = "${var.project}-Public-sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id


  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-Public-sg",
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sg_ingress_public_443" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public_sg.id
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sg_ingress_public_80" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public_sg.id
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 80
  to_port           = 80
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sg_egress_public" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public_sg.id
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "data_plane_sg" {
  name   = "${var.project}-Worker-sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-Worker-sg",
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "nodes" {
  description       = "Allow nodes to communicate with each other"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.data_plane_sg.id
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 65535
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = flatten([cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 0), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 1), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 2), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 3)])
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "nodes_inbound" {
  description       = "Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.data_plane_sg.id
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 1025
  to_port           = 65535
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = flatten([cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 2), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 3)])
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "node_outbound" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.data_plane_sg.id
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "control_plane_sg" {
  name   = "${var.project}-ControlPlane-sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-ControlPlane-sg",
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "control_plane_inbound" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.control_plane_sg.id
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 65535
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = flatten([cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 0), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 1), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 2), cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, var.subnet_cidr_bits, 3)])
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "control_plane_outbound" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.control_plane_sg.id
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 65535
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

There are more files of course, but not sure they are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create Loadbalancers automatically on the basis of service and ingress you need to deploy [`aws-load-balancer-controller`](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/) in your EKS cluster.

AWS also has official documentation at [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html).

> ! Disclaimer !! I have created the below-mentioned repo.

You can also find terraform code to deploy and use the `aws-load-balancer-controller` in this [ishuar/terraform-eks GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ishuar/terraform-eks/tree/main/examples/cluster_with_alb) along with EKS module for practical referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `aws-load-balancer-controller`.

Check [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/tree/main/helm/aws-load-balancer-controller)
and [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/deploy/installation/)